# Yii - Make a string usable in a URL or filename

Tags: php, url, yii, slug

Does the Yii framework contain a function that can make a string usable in a URL or filename ?

For example: `Health+%26+Safety+franchises` = `health-safety-franchises`

So something similar to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slugify in Django Converts to lowercase, removes non-word characters (alphanumerics and underscores) and converts spaces to hyphens. Also strips leading and trailing whitespace.
Following are the functions in PHP to carry out same tasks.

```
$slug = preg_replace('@[\s!:;_\?=\\\+\*/%&#]+@', '-', $str);
      //this will replace all non alphanumeric char with '-'
$slug = mb_strtolower($slug);
      //convert string to lowercase
$slug = trim($slug, '-');
      //trim whitespaces
```

You need to define a function in some controller TO use it in Yii

Comment: I am new to Yii and I am a bit disappointed it doesn't have a "slugify" function.. And the documentation is poor as well...

Anyway, I have written my own little function:

`public function slugify($str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', ' ', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($str));

    return mb_strtolower($str);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

It is still not completely clear what you are trying to achieve exactly.
If you want to use a string that contains characters that are not supported by the browser then you should look into php functions that can do this for you.

Perhaps
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
(there are more, depends what you need)

If you want to use your own custom encoding then specify what your trying to achieve and I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a behaviour to a model for that - [this plugin](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibehaviorsluggable/) will do the hard work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to this class into yii2

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/behaviors/SluggableBehavior.php

and see how it use this library http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-inflector.html the slug method

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)