# Yii how to make controller action with replace string

Tags: php, yii

How the best way to create action in the controller to be more user friendly???
I use it :

`http://pastebin.com/AFiBVfRs`

In every controller that I made I always put to be called from URL

```
Ex : www.domain.com/news/my-profile.html
```

With the help of the code I managed to make my page displayed properly, because the sign "-" will be replaced with "_" which made controller read the name of action.

But this method can't be used if I use a function to display the data from database .. For example: CActiveDataProvider. When I call the page always comes out error is:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId () on a non-object in / home/z65111222/framework/yiilite.php on line 3860`

Is there a better way to make my action could still be called using the sign "-" instead of "_"

Comment: URL manager will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of what you want should be

[custom url friendly class](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/urlrouter)

If you have no idea about above class for what purpose, just read

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes

Once you got the idea, and want to do more custom on your own, this link would help

[Yii - Make a string usable in a URL or filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199154/yii-make-a-string-usable-in-a-url-or-filename)

At last, if you want the suffix `.html`, just add below line into `urlMamanager` (on your app config)

```
'urlSuffix'=> '.html',
```